# Not sure what drill bit to use for 6mm masonry anchor into brick

Tags: masonry, drill-bit

Similar to this question [diy.stackexchange.com#q136613](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/136613/what-size-is-this-wallplug-and-then-what-drill-size-and-type-would-i-use-for) but not sure exactly and I still don't know what I should do, so I'm opening a new one.

I have a masonry anchor that is `6x30` and want to drill into brick wall. To make a hole I only have {5/32, 3/16, 1/4} in (IINM, these are 3.97mm, 4.76mm, and 6.35mm respectively) drill bits ([Ryobi (homedepot.com)](https://www.homedepot.com/p/RYOBI-Impact-Rated-Masonry-Set-3-Piece-AR2043/308112745?source=shoppingads&locale=en-US&&mtc=Shopping-B-F_D25T-G-D25T-025_007_PWR_TOOL_ACC-Multi-NA-Feed-SMART-NA-NA-Power_Tool_Accessories&cm_mmc=Shopping-B-F_D25T-G-D25T-025_007_PWR_TOOL_ACC-Multi-NA-Feed-SMART-NA-NA-Power_Tool_Accessories-71700000086053653-58700007291967535-92700065470082024&gclid=Cj0KCQiAhMOMBhDhARIsAPVml-GT_lcnm9-E42oGukEbhzkCj-KBdOg_qIJt9xcYok14wkDK6OKJKZEaAuhlEALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds). I looked around for awhile at a local Home Depot, browsing as many sections in and outside of Ryobi but couldn't find exact 6mm diameter bit. I also went into rental dept. at Home Depot but they didn't have an exact size of bit either.

I started drilling with 3/16 bit then the anchor doesn't even "sink". Then switched to 1/4 in. bit then the masonry anchor doesn't seem to stick at all as the hole may be too wide.

What should I do? I think of the following but

- Find exact 6mm bit? I found [this (amazon.com)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B006SV2LA2) but different brand than my drill (Ryobi), which seems to like hex.
- Find a drill bit as close as possible to 6mm? Then how big the difference can be?

  - The thread I referred to above seems to handle smaller size diff, so that makes sense for that case. But in my case like I wrote above, 2 bits with I have don't work well.
- Else

I have a floodlight that I bought from ring.com and AFACT its instruction (booklet, nor [online (support.ring.com)](https://support.ring.com/hc/en-us/articles/360023026912-Setting-Up-and-Installing-your-Floodlight-Battery)) doesn't include any info about the recommended size of equipment to be used.

Masonry anchor that came with the floodlight
[image]

---

UPDATE: Thanks for the comments. I was going to try some/all of suggestions, but then I happened to find after a while that in another device I bought from the same manufacturer ([floodlight from ring.com](https://ring.com/products/smart-lighting-floodlight-battery-kit)) comes with a masonry anchor plug with a very similar size, AND the masonry drill bit 6 mm. So I just used that drill bit and 6x30 anchor indeed fit well. Problem solved for me.

> Just to make doubly-certain? when you say at 1/4" the anchor doesn't hold? you did test this with the appropriate screw in place? It won't tighten in until the screw forces it wider.

Good point. I hadn't back then.

The hole I made with 6 mm drill bit is very tight for the anchor, I agree 1/4 inch drill bit might work with the anchor plug tightens once it's screwed.

Comment: Probably want a 7/32 bit.  Would see about prices for drill bit sets rather than buying single drill bits.  Could also get a different anchor type.

Comment: The drill bits you linked to at HD have hex-shanks. Does your drill have only a quick-change hex-shank? If so, then yes, you'll have to stick with hex-shank bits. If it has a "traditional" style 3-jaw chuck, then it can accept _any_ bit at all. Also, whatever type of chuck it has, just because it's a Ryobi drill does _not_ mean you have to have Ryobi brand drill bits, no matter _what_ the marketing seems to suggest.

Comment: Just to make doubly-certain… when you say at 1/4" the anchor doesn't hold… you *did* test this with the appropriate screw in place? It won't tighten in until the screw forces it wider.

Comment: A 1/4" hole really should work fine for a 6mm anchor. That extra 0.35mm should make no noticeable difference.

Comment: You already got it resolved, which is good. My usual method in a similar situation is to go with a smaller bit and after drilling the hole normally, widen it a bit using the same bit and moving it around. Not the best technique (especially to have the bits last a long time...) but in a pinch does the job.

Comment: I'm glad you got this figured out, but really, you want those plastic anchors to be a _snug_ fit, so you want the hole for them to be a bit smaller than the diameter of the plug, then you _hammer_ them in to ensure it doesn't go anywhere. Especially true for masonry, needs to be done gently if you're going into drywall (or you risk breaking the sheet of drywall).

Comment: @FreeMan +1. I found with 6mm drill bit the hole was very tight and the anchor didn't make it to the end so I ended up hammering it down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*From an edit the OP made to his question:*

I was going to try some/all of suggestions, but then I happened to find after a while that in another device I bought from the same manufacturer ([floodlight from ring.com](https://ring.com/products/smart-lighting-floodlight-battery-kit)) comes with a masonry anchor plug with a very similar size, AND the masonry drill bit 6 mm. So I just used that drill bit and 6x30 anchor indeed fit well.

Problem solved for me.